# Mythology geographic location of Indraloka.. Ravana and Mandodari nativity

Tags: ravana, lokas, geography, mandodari

I find it fascinating that the Indraloka been referred to in very many puranic episodes.

I for one believe it is quite a terrestrial place, not so high up in the skies as picturized in so many old films and neither can it be pure imagination. During slaying of Ravana by Rama the former said he regretted postponing construction of a stairway to Indraloka and advised Rama not to postpone important things.Indraloka may perhaps be on top of a remote tall mountain in the middle of an ocean perhaps not normally accessible even in those days.

Ayodhya, Sri Lanka, Dwarka have their locations identified now.The Rama Sethu to Sri Lanka exists now and even visible by satellite or Dwarka by underwater [SONAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonar). Their existence and location was common knowledge in those days spread merely by word of mouth.

For example, [Ahobilam Temples](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ahobilam&tbm=isch&imgil=JmswEnFIjPDqwM%253A%253B36jqv-URKWX4YM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Ftemple-of-secrets.blogspot.com%25252F2013%25252F09%25252Fahobilam-nava-narasimha-temples.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=JmswEnFIjPDqwM%253A%252C36jqv-URKWX4YM%252C_&usg=__E6v-zp1cPXjKo9vtq3t0GyKXHAo%3D&biw=1221&bih=566&ved=0ahUKEwjRxo2OwczTAhUeS48KHf-fAfYQyjcIPA&ei=eQQGWZGmEJ6WvQT_v4awDw#tbm=isch&q=ahobilam%20temples) are so ancient are well charted and even today remain places of pilgrimage. Their location spread just by popular word of mouth in those times. Modern information systems can benefit Faith with help from visually verified belief. While increasing tourism of today we can combine recreation and spirituality as desirable punyam & purushartham destinations.

EDIT1:

In a recent video SubramaniaSwamy said that [Ravana & Mandodari are of North-Indian Origin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0aqzd7d9PY)

Video references Ravana as from village Basrak near Noida U.P., video time 34m 24s and Mandodari from near Meerut U.P., video time 34-49. Also [Ravana & Mandodari](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=om1yTuV7PaU) at 10 min 55 secs. Any historical references available, that they are not native Sri Lankans but originate from towns in far away India ?

Comment: North pole has few similarities to svarga loka - it is at the north of earth, and everything else is to the south of it. svarga loka's direction is also north. it has 6 months daylight, and 6 months nighttime. 6 months of uttarayana human time equals one daytime for devas, and 6 months of dakshinayana equals one night time for devas, thus 1 human year = 1 deva day.

Comment: Interesting. Is this ( 6 months day/night) of devas mentioned in puranas?

Comment: of course - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time , http://veda.wikidot.com/vedic-time-system

Comment: "The mountain-rings that engird Sumeru are surrounded by a vast ocean, which fills most of the world. The ocean is in turn surrounded by a circular mountain wall called Cakravāḍa which marks the horizontal limit of the world."

Comment: "The world "of the Thirty-three (devas)" is a wide flat space on the top of Mount Sumeru, filled with the gardens and palaces of the devas. Its ruler is Śakra devānām indra, "Śakra, lord of the devas". Besides the eponymous Thirty-three devas, many other devas and supernatural beings dwell here, including the attendants of the devas and many apsarases(nymphs). The beings of this world are 1,500 feet (460 m) tall and live for 36,000,000 years (Sarvāstivāda tradition) or 3/4 of a yojana tall and live for 30,000,000 years. The height of this world is **80 yojanas** above the Earth."

Comment: Only 1200-1500 Km above (80 yojans).

Comment: May be found in which pouranic source?

Comment: @Narasimham these are words if Gautam Buddha. Due to his enlightenment we can accept these words on cosmology.

Comment: Dwaraka city don't exist now underwater.

Comment: Indeed it does. I had seen its re-construction model in Birla Mandir Hyderabad and some confirming related archeology researches in the museum.May be you can obtain information from the curator.UNESCO research. http://www.gounesco.com/where-mythology-meets-reality-sunken-city-of-dwarka/

Comment: "neither can it be pure imagination" why not? Most of the places have never been found and if they were found evidence shows they never looked the way described in the scriptures.

Comment: The title of your question is vague. The body looks like a discussion than a question. It's not clear what is that you are looking for. Voting to close as **Needs details or clarity**.

Comment: The title is clear about seeking geographical locations in the Indian subcontinent for references in scriptures or mythology. Distances between Ayodhya and Lanka for example are big and people are curious about travel modes etc. Readers are also curious to know and perhaps why they upvoted. Any suggestion about improving clarity are quite welcome.